# Prove that if a|c and b|c, and a and b are relatively prime, than ab|c

Tags: proof-writing

How do I show this? I have an idea of what to do, but the problem overall is a little confusing to me. I can start the problem, but I just do not see how to get to the solution.

Comment: What do you know about numbers that are relatively prime?

Comment: Their only common factor is 1.

Comment: Do you know anything about linear combinations and gcd?

Comment: Yes. So then, their GCD is 1, and by Euclidean Algorithm, there exists numbers s and t such that sa + bt = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

From the given information, $c=aj$ and $c=bk$ for some $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  And $am+bn=1$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore $c=amc+bnc$.

Can you take it from here?  You need to get $c = ab\cdot(\text{integer})$

Comment: I think so. So check my math here:

c = amc + bnc.

If we subsitute the values for c, we get c = am(bk) + bn(aj).
Next, we subsitute out an ab, so c = ab(mk+nj)?

Comment: That looks reasonable!